# mysqldump error LOCK TABLES

Tags: database, mysql

When I execute a mysqldump I get following error:

```
mysqldump -u root -ppassword --databases information_schema > test.sql
mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema' when using LOCK TABLES
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Depends on your storage engine. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104612/run-mysqldump-without-locking-tables?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to add --single-transaction

According to the MySQL manual this option guarantees only a consistent backup if you are using InnoDB or BDB. In contrast to MyISAM and Heap they support transactions.

Answer (score 6):

If you must dump the information_schema database then add --skip-lock-tables to it.

> mysqldump does not dump the
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA database by
>   default. As of MySQL 5.1.38, mysqldump
>   dumps INFORMATION_SCHEMA if you name
>   it explicitly on the command line,
>   although currently you must also use
>   the --skip-lock-tables  option. Before
>   5.1.38, mysqldump silently ignores INFORMATION_SCHEMA even if you name it
>   explicitly on the command line.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: In InnoDB use the --single-transaction parameter for the expected effect http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_lock-tables

Answer (score 0):

Got same problem yesterday.

The database was migrated from other server and when we deleled few users, there was VIEW which had nonexistent DEFINER and that caused the problem.

It doesn't show propper error when it was dumped with user grant SELECT, LOCK TABLES, but under root user correct error was shown.